# Is it possible to stream GKE logs to multiple GCP project StackDrivers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am looking to split the logs on the StackDriver Agent (SDA) to multiple GCP projects (StackDrivers) based on some filter. By default SDA targets GCP project where resides.
There is a SDA configuration option, to setup different GCP destination project id, but only one.

SDA as a FluentD wrapper uses for the match section, type ***google_cloud***.

Does this mean that the only solution is to write a custom FluentD filter that rely on the google_cloud and targets multiple GCP projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can not split logs on Stackdriver Monitoring Agent to send in different GCP project’s Stackdrivers based on any filter. I understand that you went through the document [1] and want to be confirmed about the option “type google_cloud”.

Here, the configuration options will let you override LogEntry labels [2] and MonitoredResource labels [3] when ingesting logs to Stackdriver Logging and “type google_cloud” for cloud resources of all types.

[1]:- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#label-setup

[2]:- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry

[3]:- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/MonitoredResource

Answer (score 0):

If you write your own Stackdriver logger, you can do anything you want.

The Google Stackdriver logging (the driver) does not support streaming parts of logs to different Stackdriver Logs (the service).

Comment: You can deploy your own fluentd daemonset and do what you like with that, but the managed fluentd that's installed when you enable Stackdriver Logging does not give you that control.